# Issue when using linked server to pass a parameterized dynamic query from SQL Server to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, dynamic, linked-server, parameterized-query

I'm trying to query a MySQL database using a linked server from a SQL Server database. I have created a parameterized dynamic SQL query and when I run it, it does not error, but it returns 0 rows.

If I hard-code the parameters it returns data for the row I request.

Is there a trick to dealing with MySQL when it comes to parameterized queries?

This syntax returns 0 rows:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @Params VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL, ''SELECT LoanNumber  
             FROM plms.vw__bid_dd_overlay 
             WHERE LoanNumber IN (@MyParams);'')'

SET @Params = '1000001289,1000001294,1000001296,1000001303,1000001304,1000001306,1000001308'; 

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@MyParams VARCHAR(MAX)', @Params
```

This returns 7:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL, ''SELECT LoanNumber  
                                              FROM plms.vw__bid_dd_overlay 
                                              WHERE LoanNumber IN  (1000001289,1000001294,1000001296,1000001303,1000001304,1000001306,1000001308);'')'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare the a statement and then execute it:

```
SET @Params = '1000001289,1000001294,1000001296,1000001303,1000001304,1000001306,1000001308'; 

SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT LoanNumber  
         FROM plms.vw__bid_dd_overlay 
         WHERE LoanNumber IN (' , @MyParams , ' );';

PREPARE statement FROM @SQL;

EXECUTE statement;
```

[Reference to the mySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: Based on the syntax provided in your answer, I believe you are going from MySQL to MSSQL?  I’m working in MSSQL and I am trying to pull data from a linked server that is connecting to a MySQL server.   Also, I should add that I’m in MSSQL 2008 R2.

Comment: well, if you are querying mySQL you have to put the statement in a way that mySQL understands it. Did you already tried string concat with your SQL Server query?

Comment: CONCAT is not a valid statement in MSSQL 2008 R2.  The issue is due to the fact that my comma delimited list of ids is too long for what a linked server can handle.  It's well over 8000 characters, which is the max. I can make it work using the second method in my post and using NTIME and a cursor to get all my data, but performance is not great.  I have no issues with NULLs or anything else so using a “+” to concatenate my data is working fine.  I’m just hoping to use a parameterized dynamic SQL query to get around the 8K character limit.